# running python file with a bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to run a python file with bash script for a certain time of the day. I script.sh like this (ofcourse execute it with chmod +x before)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    python /home/user/file.py
```

and with crontab -e 
I wrote

```
    * 01 * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

How can I make it run on 1 o'clock?

Edit: I have to run python file from a script because I will add some other things later.

Comment: You can just call the python command directly from cron. So do `* 01 * * * python /home/user/file.py`

Comment: whats the problem with your implementation? does it fail to execute?

Comment: Thank you @NoelEvans but I will add script some other things. I need to run it from the script. Isn't there a way to do it?

Comment: What is is the problem with how your currently have it ?

Comment: Ok but I think your command looks right. Is it not running? If not, maybe try one of the fixes suggested here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Comment: The 3rd point of this answer looks a good first bet to try if you don't know what else to do: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343

Comment: Make sure you use the full path to `python`. cron does not set `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a shebang/directive in the python script you're trying to run.

Similar to the shell script you gave, this should be the first line in your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

...or for python version 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```